# Auto_value_parcel issue

Tags: android

I can not properly adjust the gradle.

"Warning:android-apt plugin is incompatible with future version of Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead."

I've tried many options, but I can not really write

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hipair.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    apt 'frankiesardo:auto-parcel:1.0.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

    provided 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
    apt 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'

    provided 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.6'
    apt 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.6'
    apt 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.5'

    compile 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel-adapter:0.2.5'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
}


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha6'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of android-apt is now part of the android plugin. To migrate to use the builtin annotation processor remove the line

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

from you gradle file and replace `apt` with `annotationProcessor`.